# TFS SDK Code metrics

Tags: tfs-sdk

I am making some kind of wrapper around the TFS SDK.
I would like to query the code metrics from a given project on a given URL.

MS Visual studio has a feature to calculate the code metrics inside the IDE. Is it possible to do this on a TFS server and query it from the Warehouse ? I would be interested in

- cyclometic complexity
- depth of inheritance
- class coupling
- lines of code
- maintainability index

and even more metrics if it is possible

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [this](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9422) utility, you can generate a "metrics.xml" for each project/solution.
 I am using TFS2010 & have inserted this as a build step, following [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2011/01/30/integrating-code-metrics-in-tfs-2010-build.aspx) guide by J.Ehn.
Those results are not inserted into TFS-persistency in any means - but in theory, you could set up an own database where this output shall be inserted. From then on, you could retrieve as you wish.

Comment: Is there no standard build-in database in TFS that one could query in terms of code quality metrics ?

Comment: Is it possible to extend the TFS server so that this is possible?

I would like to have this information stored at the server and be able to query this information with the TFS SDK.

Comment: The TFS data warehouse currently doesn't store Code Metrics, but the schema is available and you're free to add fields and change the Analysis Cube. It would make upgrades in the future a pain though, keep that in mind! You need to add your data to the BuildDetails in the TFS database first. Then later you can transfer that data into the datawarehouse. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130342(v=vs.90).aspx (2008) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx#ServerWarehouse (2010)